# Filtro excel - Ruby on Rails

Tags: excel, ruby-on-rails

Tengo un formulario de productos, creada con *scaffold*, yo exporto mis registros normalmente a mi excel con la configuración vigente de *csv y excel* en Ruby on Rails; quiero saber si hay forma de exportar solo los productos que yo quiero o determinados por su nombre, no he encontrado nada relacionado en internet y no tengo la más remota idea cómo hacerlo. Puesto a que llevo poco tiempo en esta labor, espero su pronta respuesta o alguna página en la cual me pueda apoyar.

Controlador:

```
# app/controllers/products.rb

class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.order(:name)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @products.to_csv }
      format.xls
    end
  end
end
```

Vista:

```
<!-- app/views/products/index.xls.erb -->

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Release Date</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= product.id %></td>
    <td><%= product.name %></td>
    <td><%= product.released_on %></td>
    <td><%= product.price %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola @stiven, ¿podrías mostrar el código con el que actualmente exportas a excel?

Comment: Hola @Gerry mi código es tal cual el de esta pagina...    http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?language=es&view=asciicast   Puedes mirarla por favor y me puedes sugerir o explicar mi pregunta, te lo agradezco.    No se si me hice entender bien, osea para exportar no tengo ningún problema, solo quiero hacer un filtro para que no se vallan todos los registros, solo los que yo quiero o los de determinado nombre ejemplo :Camiseta, que se exporten solo las camisetas, si me hago entender ?

Comment: @Gerry me gustaria seguirte mas de cerca, tienes redes sociales ? quiero aprender de ti...

Comment: Para aprovechar al máximo la ayuda que puedes obtener, te recomiendo darte una vuelta por el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour); así conocerás mejor el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El único cambio que debes hacer filtrar la coleccion **antes** de exportarla a *CSV* o *XLS*, es decir, en el controlador; en tu ejemplo se vería algo así:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.where(name: 'Camiseta')

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @products.to_csv }
      format.xls { send_data @products.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") }
    end
  end
end
```

La línea importante es `@products = Product.where(name: 'Camiseta')`, en la cual estás filtrando los productos para incluir únicamente los que se llaman `'Camiseta'`.

Comment: Listo perfecto, y si lo quiero manejar con una lista despegable, donde se seleccione "Camiseta" , "Pantalon", "Etc...", y se descargue respectivamente, o por medio de un buscador...

Comment: @stiven Podrías agregar un `select` en la vista y luego utilizar _javascript_ para que la selección del usuario se envíe como parámetro en el _link_ generado; y dentro del controlador recibir el parámetro para filtrar el producto. Te sugiero que lo intentes por tu cuenta (es la mejor manera de aprender) y si te atoras en un paso, regresa acá y abre una pregunta con el código que estés probando en ese momento.

Comment: muchas gracias, si funciona

Comment: @stiven Excelente! Y no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada (dando clic a la paloma). Suerte!

Comment: tienes redes sociales ? me gustaria seguirte

Comment: @stiven No cuento con redes sociales (soy de la especie rara que no le gustan), pero frecuento mucho este sitio, así que puedo ayudarte en tus dudas a través de SO; además, al abrir preguntas aquí puedes encontrar más ayuda, no solo la mía.